# Join mysql tables one after the other using python

Tags: python, mysql

I am new to both python and mysql. I want to join 21 mysql tables one after the other using python.

I know there is `UNION ALL` function in mysql which can do it. But, How to do it in python.

My code is

```
import MySQLdb

  db = MySQLdb.connect()
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor1 = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute("SELECT * from table 1")
  cursor1.execute("SELECT * from table 2")
```

now where to use UNION ALL ...Do I need to create 21 cursors for it...

Comment: What kind of format do you want python to return after union several query results? List? Dict? Or String?

Answer (score 0):

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect()

cursor = db.cursor()

sql="SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2
UNION ALL;"

'''repeat for 21 table'''

try:

    cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()
except:

    db.rollback()

#I think this will do the join
```

Comment: use only one cursor.Write(sql) the union all for each table syntax, then at last use cursor.execute(sql).for action

Comment: can you please edit the post and add some details about what you've changed and why? it can help the author of the question to better understand what you did and it surely increases the value of your answer

Comment: Thanks deep.Its doing the job but its taking a long time to combine 2 files. I guess it will take forever for the 21 files to join. My file are very big. Is there any faster way to combine them.